# UITabBar Badge from array.count

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, badge

how in swift can I add to `UITabBar` `Badge` counts from array.count?

I have `UserDefaults` array, and I want to display number of changeable  array counts in `Badge`, please help

Comment: Duplicate? Seriously? From array?

Comment: @Bogdan59, you just need to get value from `array` and set like this : `self.tabBar.items?[2].badgeValue = "12"` in your `UITabBarController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the class of your view controller where you need to set badge value.

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    static weak var shared: YourViewController?


    override function viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        YourViewController.shared = self
    }




   public func updateBadgeValue() {

      guard let array = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "yourKeyOfStoredArray") as? [Any]  else { //raplace yourKeyOfStoredArray to the key you use to store the array

         print("Don't have a stored array for key yourKeyOfStoredArray")
         return
      }

      guard let items = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items else { // Only if you use tab bar controller, if no delete this scope and uncomment next

         print("Don't have tab bar controller")
         return
       }


       /*
        guard let items = self.tabBar.items  else { // replace tabBar by reffence to your tab bar @IBOutlet

            print("Don't have tab bar")
            return
         }*/



         let index = 0 //<-The index of the tabbar item which you need to set badge value

         if items.count > index {
             items[index].badgeValue = String(array.count)
         } else {
                print("Don't have item at index \(index)")
         }
    }
}
```

This is the class of view controller where you need to tap a button to update badge value of YourViewController.

```
class AnotherViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBAction func buttonPressed() {
       YourViewController?.shared.updateBadgeValue()
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is work, but how I can change badge.count in first VC if in the second ViewController Im tap the Button?

Comment: @Bogdan59 Ok, but why you didn't specify this in question body?

Comment: @Bogdan59, see updates and update the question.

Comment: Im updates your code, but when I tap Button -  badge in another ViewController not change number count

Comment: @Bogdan59, so show us the code you are using... I can't guess what is wrong if I don't see the code.